# Systemd: Run a command before shutdown, while network is still up

Tags: networking, systemd

I'm trying to get Systemd to run a script that sends out an email before the computer shuts down. I understand Systemd terminates services in the reverse order they are started, so if you put `After=network.target`, your service is shut down before `network.target`.

However, no matter how many damn depenencies I put on the `After=` and `Wants=` lines, the network connection goes down before my email script runs. Occasionally it will send an email, but the vast majority of times it doesn't. This tells me there is a race condition and Systemd is not waiting for my script to finish before it shuts down the networking service.

My unit file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Send email before shutdown
Wants=network.target nss-lookup.target network-online.target networking.service NetworkManager.service network-manager.service
After=network.target nss-lookup.target network-online.target networking.service NetworkManager.service network-manager.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/home/user1/send_email.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The journal says:

```
Jun 20 13:13:14 caesar systemd[1]: Stopped Availability of block devices.
Jun 20 13:13:14 caesar NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1559301194.4305] device (wlx24050fd83726): state change: deactivating -> discon
Jun 20 13:13:14 caesar NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1559301194.4629] dhcp4 (wlx24050fd83726): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP clien
Jun 20 13:13:14 caesar NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1559301194.4629] dhcp4 (wlx24050fd83726): state changed bound -> done
Jun 20 13:13:14 caesar NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1559301194.4648] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jun 20 13:13:14 caesar NetworkManager[699]: <warn>  [1559301194.4661] sup-iface[0xb4fd40,wlx24050fd83726]: connection disconnected (
Jun 20 13:13:14 caesar NetworkManager[699]: <info>  [1559301194.4662] device (wlx24050fd83726): supplicant interface state: complete
Jun 20 13:13:14 caesar send_email.sh[21782]: s-nail:  Certificate depth 2
Jun 20 13:13:14 caesar send_email.sh[21782]: s-nail:   subject = /C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert 

....

Jun 20 13:13:56 caesar send_email.sh[21782]: s-nail: could not initiate SSL/TLS connection: error:00000000:lib(0):func
```

I don't think it should be this difficult. I'd appreciate any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Adding more dependencies not always helps, since if you end up creating a dependency loop, systemd will break one of the dependencies to break the loop, and it might end up being exactly the one you needed... Try to remove the ,`Wants=` and keeping *only* `After=network.target` since that's the only one you need

Comment: Also, do you have a line `Stopped Send email before shutdown` in your journal logs? That might help check when it's running the script... Does `send_email.sh` run anything in background? Or does it block until the email is sent? Does this work if you run `systemctl stop <your-service-name>` on the command line when the system is up and running? Can you check if the service is `running` right before shutdown, with `systemctl status`?

Comment: The `systemd-analyze` tool can be useful to debug this kind of issue. See [`systemd-analyze dump`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-analyze.html#systemd-analyze%20dump) for example, or `systemd-analyze plot`. You can also use it to increase logging. Most of `systemd-analyze` is tailored towards startup (time to start, etc.) but it can be helpful checking shutdown problems too...

Answer (score 1):

You should also specify a "Requires=network.target" line.  More info at https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-unit-dependencies-and-order/